# How do I correctly pass a shared list to a Process or Thread?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing

I want to start a new process that executes some .py file. The new process gets information from the parent process via the stdin. The new process sends information (=results) back to the parent process via stdout. The results should be saved in a list (or similar) in the parent process. Sounds quite easy to accomplish but I'm stuck...
Here is my code:

```
class MultiProcessTest:
    results: list = []
    path = 'xxx.py'

# This method will be called in main
def do_it(self):
    # The self.results list gets passed to the newly created process
    proc = Process(target=self._control, args=(self.results, self.path)
    proc.start()
    proc.join()
    # At this point the newly created process should be done with processing and all
    # generated results should be stored in the self.results list
    # But the list is empty!
    print(self.results)

def _control(self, results: list, path):
    with Popen(path, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, stdin=PIPE) as proc:
        #  I'm starting a thread for error handling
        err_thread = threading.Thread(target=_read_errors, args=(proc,), daemon=True)
        err_thread.start()

        # This thread gets the results list passed as an argument and will be waiting for 
        # results of the newly created process
        receive_thread = threading.Thread(target=_receive, args=(results, proc.stdout))
        receive_thread.start()

        # In the real code I send some instructions at this point to the newly created 
        # process via stdin

        receive_thread.join()
```

The receive function which is running in a own thread looks like that:

```
    def _receive(results: list, pipe: IO):
        line = pipe.readline().decode('utf-8')
        while line is not '':
            results.append(results)
            line = pipe.readline().decode('utf-8')
```

I checked if the receive function is actually called, which it is. The receive function writes results to the list as expected. Unfortunately the list in the parent process remains empty.
I guess it has to do something with call-by-value/call-by-reference or with shared or not shared memory.

So...can anyone explain to me why the list stays empty?

Thanks in advance, your help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Is there some reason you are doing it this way? Why start multiple processes explicitly by starting multiple .py files and try to share data over stdout when you could use the Python multiprocessing library to spawn multiple processes from a single start point and use the provided synchronisation types?

Comment: Very good question, thank you. I didn't make that clear. Right now I'm testing it with .py files. In the long run any executable should be used.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem.
With this line I'm spawning the process that will execute some worker program:

```
with Popen(path, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, stdin=PIPE) as proc:
```

While I do want the worker program to run in a new process, I don't want to spawn a new process at this point:

```
proc = Process(target=self._control, args=(self.results, self.path)
```

If I call self._control directly everything is working fine :)